# Ruby Postgresql PGconn.connect takes up to 60 seconds to initialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, postgresql, startup

Trying to do some rails dev under windows and I'm finding that the initial connection to postgres is taking up to 60 seconds. I dug into the activerecord postgresql adapter and added some profiling in the connect method.

```
      require 'ruby-prof'
      GC::Profiler.enable
      GC.start
      RubyProf.start
      p @connection_parameters
      @connection = PGconn.connect(@connection_parameters)
      result = RubyProf.stop
      printer = RubyProf::FlatPrinter.new(result)
      printer.print(STDOUT)
      puts GC::Profiler.report
      STDOUT.flush
```

This gives the following output:

Measure Mode: wall_time
    Thread ID: 7790520
    Fiber ID: 7613460
    Total: 52.288858
    Sort by: self_time

```
 %self      total      self      wait     child     calls  name
 99.94     52.258    52.257     0.000     0.001        1   PG::Connection#initialize
  0.06      0.031     0.031     0.000     0.000        1   Kernel#p
  0.00      0.001     0.001     0.000     0.000        1   Array#pop
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        1   String#sub
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        1   Array#each
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        3   Symbol#to_s
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        1   Hash#each
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        1   Enumerable#map
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        1   Hash#merge!
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        1   Array#zip
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        3   String#to_s
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000       36   Symbol#to_sym
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        3   <Class::PG::Connection>#quote_connstr
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        1   Enumerable#find
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        1   Module#instance_methods
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        3   String#gsub
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        1   Kernel#is_a?
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        1   Array#last
  0.00      0.001     0.000     0.000     0.001        1   <Class::PG::Connection>#parse_connect_args
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        1   Array#join
  0.00     52.258     0.000     0.000    52.258        1   <Class::PG::Connection>#connect
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        2   String#inspect
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        2   Symbol#inspect
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        1   Hash#inspect
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        1   String#%
  0.00     52.289     0.000     0.000    52.289        1   ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter#connect

* indicates recursively called methods
GC 36 invokes.
Index    Invoke Time(sec)       Use Size(byte)     Total Size(byte)         Total Object                    GC Time(ms)
    1              12.609             12175480             22293120               557328       125.00000000000000000000
```

If I strip away everything else and just pass the exact some connection parameters to PGconn.connect without loading rails or any other libraries, I can connect in 2 seconds:

```
$ time PGUSER=username PGPASSWORD=password ruby -rpg -rruby-prof -e "GC::Profiler.enable; GC.start; RubyProf.start; settings = {:host => 'localhost', :dbname => 'dbname_development'}; PGconn.connect(settings); r=RubyProf.stop; RubyProf::FlatPrinter.new(r).print(STDOUT); puts GC::Profiler.report; STDOUT.flush"
Measure Mode: wall_time
Thread ID: 20316120
Fiber ID: 20135520
Total: 2.675508
Sort by: self_time

 %self      total      self      wait     child     calls  name
100.00      2.676     2.676     0.000     0.000        1   PG::Connection#initialize
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        1   String#sub
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        3   String#to_s
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        3   <Class::PG::Connection>#quote_connstr
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        3   Symbol#to_s
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        1   Hash#each
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        1   Enumerable#map
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        1   Hash#merge!
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        1   Array#zip
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        3   String#gsub
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000       46   Symbol#to_sym
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        1   Array#each
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        1   Enumerable#find
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        1   Module#instance_methods
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        1   Array#pop
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        1   Kernel#is_a?
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        1   Array#last
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        1   <Class::PG::Connection>#parse_connect_args
  0.00      0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000        1   Array#join
  0.00      2.676     0.000     0.000     2.676        1   <Class::PG::Connection>#connect

* indicates recursively called methods
GC 14 invokes.
Index    Invoke Time(sec)       Use Size(byte)     Total Size(byte)         Total Object                    GC Time(ms)
    1               0.562               895840              1338240                33456        15.62500000000000000000


real    0m3.795s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.046s
```

As I add more an more required libraries, the connection time increases. I think libraries that include native components might make more of an impact, but not 100% on that. It's using more memory, but it's not hitting swap, and the GC time isn't significantly more.

Any pointers on which rabbit hole to go down to investigate further?

Running versions:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x64-mingw32]

$ gem list pg --local
pg (0.19.0 x64-mingw32)
```